# Azure DataFactory Salesforce (data read != data written)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to figure out why the data read is different from the data written in my azure datafactory. The extract is from salesforce accounts into a table with the exact same schema.

```
"dataRead": 1094945,
"dataWritten": 817359,
```

Where would I go to figure out the issue?

Comment: What's the data type of transformed column?

Comment: String in salesforce, varchar max in db

Answer (score 0):

Is there any pre-copy script you were using in Copy activity.

Comment: Nope. Just their basic connection to sf